# How to filter Year-to-date data using Dplyr in R?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This question is extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438355/how-to-display-year-to-date-data-in-shinydashboard-r?noredirect=1#comment101354656_57438355). Essentially, I am trying to filter dates based on user selection. I was able to get correct output for the year 2018 and 2019. However, when I select Year as 0, the output is displaying data from the year 2018,2019 and 0. All I want to see is when user selects year 2019, It should show data related to 2019 including 2018 and 0. When user selects 2018, the output should be related to year 2018 and 0. However, when user selects year 0, only data related to year 0 should be filtered and display. Which below code is not doing.

Any help is appreciated!

**Dataset:**

```
structure(list(Systems = c("Sys1", "Sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3", "Sys4", 
"Sys6", "Sys7"), Locations = c("loc1", "loc1", "loc1", "loc2", 
"loc2", "loc3", "loc1"), year = c(2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
0, 0), frequency = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), freq_cal = c(33.33, 
66.67, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0), label = c("33.33%", "66.67%", "100.00%", 
"100.00%", "100.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%")), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code use to filter:**

```
d %>%
  filter(year<=2019 |year==0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to `filter` all the `year` below a certain number

```
library(dplyr)

select_data <- function(d, num) {
   d %>% filter(year <= num) 
}

select_data(d, 2019)

#  Systems Locations year frequency freq_cal   label
#1    Sys1      loc1 2018         1    33.33  33.33%
#2    Sys1      loc1 2019         2    66.67  66.67%
#3    Sys2      loc1 2019         1   100.00 100.00%
#4    Sys3      loc2 2019         1   100.00 100.00%
#5    Sys4      loc2 2019         1   100.00 100.00%
#6    Sys6      loc3    0         0     0.00   0.00%
#7    Sys7      loc1    0         0     0.00   0.00%

select_data(d, 2018)
#  Systems Locations year frequency freq_cal  label
#1    Sys1      loc1 2018         1    33.33 33.33%
#2    Sys6      loc3    0         0     0.00  0.00%
#3    Sys7      loc1    0         0     0.00  0.00%

select_data(d, 0)
#  Systems Locations year frequency freq_cal label
#1    Sys6      loc3    0         0        0 0.00%
#2    Sys7      loc1    0         0        0 0.00%
```

The same logic can be implemented only using base R as well

```
select_data <- function(d, num) {
   subset(d, year <= num)
}
```

Comment: ..I was just curious if there is Dplyr version of filtering the data ?

Comment: @biggboss2019 the first approach using `filter` (`d %>% filter(year <= num)`) is a dplyr way of filtering the data.

Comment: ..correct..however when I pass data_filter<- function(d,loc,num) {d %>% filter(Locations==loc)%>%filter(year <= num) }data_filter(d,input$slct1,input$slct2)..in ShinyServer renderUI part..It is still displaying the data associated with the year 2018,2019 and 0, when 0 is selected.

Comment: Please see update Shiny code here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438355/how-to-display-year-to-date-data-in-shinydashboard-r?noredirect=1#comment101354656_57438355

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[year <= 2019]
```

Comment: Thanks! This could be another option. If possible can you please see updated shiny code located here. I am able to filter the years 2018, and 2019. However, I am struggling to filter the data for the year 0.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438355/how-to-display-year-to-date-data-in-shinydashboard-r